# two equations with 2 variables

Tags: polynomials

How can I find one point (x,y) wherefore these equations are accepted?

$-x^2 -x -y^2 +3y = 0$ and $2x^2 -3x + 2y^2 -y = 0$

The solution is (1,1). I don't think it's a hard question but I forgot how to solve this >.<. Is it with a matrix you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiply eq.1 by $2$ and subtract from 2 to get $x=y$

Comment: Thank you. I managed to find the answer so we get $y=x$ and afterwards we use this new equation in one of the two given equations. This gave me the point (0,0) and (1,1)

Answer (score 1):

Strong hint: Multiply the first euqation by two and subtract it from the second one.